# How to create view declaratively for sharepoint list?

Tags: 2013, view, xml

I have a web part in which I am displaying the item title as a link. I want user to redirect to the custom view which displays only that product information. I need to pass the query string parameter when user clicks on the link.

My code for view is:

```
<View BaseViewID="2" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:OPLBIntranet,procedureViewDisplayName;" MobileView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" Url="procedures.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="oiplbDepartment"/>
      <FieldRef Name="oiplbQmsDocApprover1"/>
      <FieldRef Name="oiplbQmsDocApprover2"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
</View>
```

I copied the view from the allitems.aspx view in List's schema file but I donot have much idea about how to bind parameters and configure the query based on parameter.

How do I configure the query and bind parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Query String (URL) web part to the page, then configure the web part by choosing Edit -> Connections -> Send filter values to ...